# Debug an obfuscated jar file within an obfuscated apk

Tags: android, debugging, sdk, jar, obfuscation

suppose i create an sdk inside a single jar file , and i also obfuscate it .

the developer takes the jar file and use it in an app , and then the app is being obfuscated .

now , **here's the question:** if the app crashes because of the sdk , is it possible that i take the app's obfuscated apk and try to debug it , and enter the code i've created for the sdk ?

if so, how do i do that? also , is there a best pracice for obfuscating such sdk's jar files?